# Porcentaje a una variable de repeating-linear-gradient en CSS

Tags: css

Tengo que pasarle un porcentaje a una variable de repeating-linear-gradient en CSS pero no me esta tomando los porcentajes.

La línea de código es la siguiente lo que no esta correcto en teoría es el 0% 5% de la variable **`--building-color2`**:

```
El :root del que viene el --building-color2
:root {
  --building-color1: #aa80ff;
  --building-color2: #66cc99;
  --building-color3: #cc6699;
  --building-color4: #538cc6;
  --window-color1: #bb99ff;
  --window-color2: #8cd9b3;
  --window-color3: #d98cb3;
  --window-color4: #8cb3d9;


background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    var(--building-color2)0% 5% , transparent 5% 10%);
```

Answer (score 2):

Logre resolverlo. Usando esta linea de codigo:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
   
    var(--building-color2),
    var(--building-color2) 5%,
    transparent 5%,
    transparent 10%
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar un porcentaje a una variable de repeating-linear-gradient en CSS, simplemente debes escribir el valor del porcentaje dentro de la definición de la variable. Por ejemplo:

```
:root {
  --building-color2: repeating-linear-gradient(#fff 0% 5%, #ccc 5% 10%);
}
```

En este caso, la variable --building-color2 se define con un gradiente repetitivo que va desde el color blanco (#fff) hasta el color gris claro (#ccc) con un primer ciclo que va desde el 0% hasta el 5% y un segundo ciclo que va desde el 5% hasta el 10%. Puedes ajustar los valores de los colores y los porcentajes a tu gusto.

Luego, puedes utilizar la variable en la propiedad background de cualquier elemento, como se muestra en el ejemplo a continuación:

```
.element {
  background: var(--building-color2);
}
```

Con esto, la variable --building-color2 se aplicará como fondo de .element, incluyendo el gradiente repetitivo con los porcentajes que hayas definido en la variable.

Comment: Probe poniendolos por separado tambien, no hay forma, me dice "Debe dar al repeating-linear-gradient un primer color de --building-color2 de 0% a 5%." aun con los espacios no lo toma como correcto (estoy haciendo el curso de freecodecamp)

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pone el **root** de donde viene **--building-color2**. Probra pasar el porcentaje de **repeating-linear-gradient** como lo describo en la respuesta de arriba